# Facebook Like not appearing , if Url has "/" "%2F" in end

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-likebox

Our website url is ending with slash "/", it get encoded to "%2F". because of this slash facebook like button is not showing on the website.

Eg

Not working url: because in href parameter url has "%2F", but if i remove the "%2f", it starts working. Earlier it was working fine.

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?action=like&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D9%23cb%3Df3e1268db4%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.bcgperspectives.com%252Ff189b4c84c%26domain%3Dwww.bcgperspectives.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&extended_social_context=false&font=arial&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bcgperspectives.com%2Fcontent%2Fvideos%2Fleadership_paul_deighton_organizing_london_2012_olympics**%2F**&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&ref=.UCfPf5lBPRI.like&sdk=joey&show_faces=false&width=90

any solution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can’t get a like button shown on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ when I input your URL https://www.bcgperspectives.com/content/videos/leadership_paul_deighton_organizing_london_2012_olympics/, no matter whether the trailing slash is there or not.

However, it does get shown if I use `http://` instead of `https://` in front of your URL – then it works for both versions, the one with the trailing slash and the one without.

An interesting fact though is, that I can not see any information scraped from your page using the [debug tool on your URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://www.bcgperspectives.com/content/videos/leadership_paul_deighton_organizing_london_2012_olympics/) – doesn’t matter if its the slash or no-slash version or the HTTP vs the HTTPS version, since your server redirects to the HTTPS version with the trailing slash anyway. So that *might* point to some problem FB’s scraper has with your URL/domain (although no explicit error messages are shown).

Comment: i dont know, suddenly it stopped working, but on QA machine which is not public like is working perfectly. But on public site. it does not show like button, just check before tweet there is blank screen, the URL which is pasted is from fb generated iframe, now see if you again put the complete URL without %2F at end in href var. it shows like button, so i was checking, whether its because of that.

Is it somehow related to App ID which we use for flogin, because on same page, we use fconnect also.

Comment: you are right, its some issue with URL Domain, when i go through scraper  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q={{MYURL}}, after that it start showing like button. What could be the issue. "/" or "2f" was not an issue, because when i remove /, it treat it as different URL so it started showing that. 

do you know any solution, i can not put my 2000 URL through debugger/scrapper?